# how to let the user pick an image on a website

Tags: ios, image, web, swift5

As one of the options in my app, I want to enable the user to got to images.google.com and select an image for use in the app.

I've setup a SFSafariViewController, but I have no idea how to get an image that way. Maybe i should/could respond to the copy command? If so, how? What classes do i need to implement?

```
{ (...)
            let url = URL(string: "https://images.google.com")!
            let safariViewController = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
            safariViewController.delegate = self
            self.presentationController?.present(safariViewController, animated: true)
}

//MARK: - Ext. Delegate SFSafariViewControllerDelegate
extension ProjectImagePicker: SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {
    public func safariViewControllerDidFinish(_ controller: SFSafariViewController) {
        print("SAFARI DELEGATE HIT!")
        guard let image = controller.copy() as? UIImage else { return }
        self.delegate?.didSelect(image: image)
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Can it be done using a WKWebView, if so how?

Any nudge in the right direction appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it like so:

I present a Safari ViewController. When the user long presses on an image and then selects share > copy, an image is added to the Pasteboard. Sometimes it's not an Image, but an image URL. I handle both cases:

```
//MARK: - Ext. Delegate SFSafariViewControllerDelegate
extension ProjectImagePicker: SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {
    public func safariViewControllerDidFinish(_ controller: SFSafariViewController) {
        //image was returned by Copy
        if pasteboard.hasImages {
            guard let image = pasteboard.image else { return }
            self.delegate?.didSelect(image: image)
        //Image Url was returned by Copy
        } else if pasteboard.hasURLs {
            guard let url = pasteboard.url else { return }
            print(url)
            if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
                if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                    self.delegate?.didSelect(image: image)
                }
            }
        }
        pasteboard.items.removeAll()
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Seems to work as intended!